# Undefined reference to rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Int32

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am compiling micro-ROS crystal version and want to run the publisher demo for Int32. However, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Int32'
```

I think this function should be defined somewhere but it seems that it has not been defined. Would you please tell me in which library I should find this function?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344507/undefined-reference-to-rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type-support_handle__std_msgs__msg__int32/) by [Saeid Dehnavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/51895/saeid-dehnavi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-02-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-19**:
You may want to post this as an issue on the appropriate micro-ros issue tracker. The intersection between micro-ros developers/users and ROS Answers frequenters is probably not very big, so it may take quite some time before you get a response here.

**Comment by [Saeid Dehnavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/51895/saeid-dehnavi/) on 2020-02-19**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn, but since this problem is related to the ROS typesupport which is shared between normal ROS2 and microROS, I decided to post my question here :)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-19**:
@gvdhoorn I would highly recommend the micro-ros developers to watch answers.ros.org and specifically the `micro-ROS` tag.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-02-19**:
@saeid-dehnavi I have add the `micro-ROS` tag to your question since the problem happens when you compile micro-ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-19**:\

> @gvdhoorn I would highly recommend the micro-ros developers to watch answers.ros.org and specifically the `micro-ROS` tag.

Couldn't agree more, but I'm not one of them. Nor do I talk to them often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The symbol should be in `install/lib/libstd_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_c.so` for humble.

```
$ nm install/lib/libstd_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_c.so | grep rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Int32
00000000000044fc T rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Int32
000000000000454b T rosidl_typesupport_c__get_message_type_support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Int32MultiArray
```

---

Originally posted by [yashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/119278/yashi/) with karma: 26 on 2022-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does this issue still persist with newer versions (for Dashing or ideally Foxy)? We have improved the tutorials a lot in the last months. Please let us know if you face any issues with them. If you want to start with real microcontroller hardware, I recommend https://micro-ros.github.io/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/. If you use an ESP32, the wiring is even simpler than with the Olimex STM32-E407.
And, we promise to watch answers.ros.org more intensively!

---

Originally posted by [ralph-lange](https://answers.ros.org/users/39505/ralph-lange/) with karma: 31 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1